# How do I click on button in a Qt application from a C# application?

Tags: c#, c++, qt, winapi, ui-automation

As Qt UI controls aren't backed by native controls I can't just send a `BN_CLICKED` throught [`SendMessage()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx). So how do I click on button on a Qt application? I prefer to do it in C# but C and/or C++ solutions are welcome well.

I'm looking for equivalent of this done in win32 API:

```
SendMessage(btnHandle, BN_CLICKED, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: You've already got the answer in the tags: [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx).

Comment: Would you give some code example or a link with some code example to I begin with? I didn't got much luck with my search

Comment: What I linked to *is* the detailed documentation for UI Automation with the .NET wrapper classes, complete with code examples. Not sure what else you're looking for. There is plenty of information there to understand how to solve the problem. The next step is writing the code, and this website is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @CodyGray Qt does not support UI Automation natively, it supports MSAA and IAccessible2. UI automation clients will use a bridge to use a Qt MSAA provider application. The bridge doesn't support IAccessible2, AFAIK.

Comment: @kuba I'm not entirely sure if I understand your comment. The question is asking about C#, which would imply the .NET Framework, so *using* UI Automation from Qt is not relevant. So you must be saying that Qt's controls don't work with UI Automation? If so, expletive deleted. I've long felt that Qt was a piece of junk because it didn't use native Win32 controls. But now, if I'm hearing that its crappy non-native controls haven't even been designed to work with UI Automation, then that's completely ridiculous. I do not understand why anyone would ever use Qt. I certainly won't use apps that do.

Comment: @CodyGray No need to get upset. UI Automation bridges over to providers that only support MSAA, I've said as much. I didn't say anything about using UI Automation from Qt, but Qt still needs to provide an accessibility interface that UI Automation can use. Such interface is MSAA. There's also IAccessible2 that extends MSAA and is a cross-platform standard, whereas UI Automation is a MS-only thingo that nobody seems to care for on other platforms. As for "crappy non-native controls": get over it, no modern Windows-based products use native anything, much less controls.

Comment: @CodyGray In fact, using the GDI APIs for painting etc. like the native controls do is a sure-fire way of making your code use more power and bypass the energy-efficient GPU acceleration. GDI is dead because its API simply wasn't designed with "least draw calls and state changes are expensive" GPUs of today in mind. Native controls are married to GDI, so they are fully obsolete. WPF is the modern "native" control set on Windows.